# Strain-Displacement relationship symmetrization

Tags: classical-mechanics, stress-strain

In the context of infinitesimal elastic strain theory, one writes the relationship between displacement and strain as

$$ \epsilon_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}( \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} )$$

My question is; is the full non-simmetrized displacement tensor a meaningful mechanical quantity? what is the physical interpretation of the anti-simmetric part of the displacement gradient, that is:

$$ \omega_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}( \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} - \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} )$$

In what circumstances does this physical quantity plays a role in the structural analysis of the stresses in a material?

Comment: If you wish to rotate your principal axis around, you will find it much easier to do with the real, physically meaningful tensor formalism.  I've never liked the reduced engineering format - I think it is a relic from the dinosaur ages (much like secant and cosecant for that matter).

Comment: can you point a reference for this and elaborate a bit?

Comment: Most engineering elasticity texts end up with $\sigma_{i} = c_{i,j}\epsilon_{j}$, using $i$ and $j$ = $x,y,z,xy,xz,yz$ (only 6 elements) and throwing in the appropriate factors of 2 or 1/2 on the off-diagonal terms to make it work out right.  That is, they assume that $xy = yx$ and shove it into one index. Physics folk would recognize this better as $\sigma_{ij} = c_{ij,kl}\epsilon_{kl}$. This eliminates the need for the seemingly random factors of 2 or 1/2 on the off-diagonal elements, and makes it straightforward to use Euler formalism to rotate the axes to what you'd like them to be.

Comment: you are referring to the Voigt notation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voigt_notation

Comment: but in this case the anti-symmetric components of displacements are in principle invariant under such relabeling or axis reorientation. The anti-symmetric component of a 3x3 matrix transforms as an axial vector

Comment: Indeed, I spaced.  The $\omega_{ij}$ are called the 'components of rotation'.  For the displacement vector $u$ = (u,v,w), and $\omega$ the vector of ($\omega_{x},\omega_{y},\omega_{z}$), than $2\omega = curl u$.  If $\omega_{x} = \omega_{y} = \omega_{z} = 0$, than the strain is irrotational.  But the rotations don't affect the strains, it just can drive you nuts trying to see what is going on.

Comment: so they can be interpreted as a rigid rotation strain?

Comment: I'd say rather that they are rotation without strain...

Comment: but it is a quantity that in principle can be different at different points of the solid

Comment: Oh, absolutely, for any non-trivial strain field (i.e. not uniaxial strain, modes of plates, etc.) you need to consider it if looking at strain maps. In the sense of finite element calculations, the element can rotate but there is not stress/strain as a result, which is different from the shear deformations.

Answer (score 3):

The anti-symmetric (or skew-symmetric, if you prefer) part of the deformation gradient represents the rigid-body rotation.   As a rigid-body motion, it induces no deformation (if inertial effects are ignored) and so induces no stress.   It's therefore removed from the mechanics, leaving only the symmetric part to be related to stress.